# Writing image data as byte array along with name from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

I have image data as byte array and my servlet has to write that data to outputstream along with name.

when client reads the stream from servlet, client will save those images with the same file name.

How can I do it in servlet?

Note: Images are not available as files in server. Servlet read it from the data base.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different common image formats. Streaming the bytes from the database is one thing, but the servlet absolutely MUST set the content type to the correct image format for this to work.

For fetching the image data from the database, see [ResultSet.getBinaryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream(int))

Answer (score 0):

If the servlet is an HTTPServlet then you can do it like this:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        byte[] imageByteArray = Database.getImage();
        resp.getOutputStream().write(imageByteArray);
    }

}
```

You have to exchange the Database.getImage() with your own code of course.

It would probably also be a good idea to set the HTTP ContentType header to the type of the image.

Comment: I know that we can write byte array to outputstream, but I want to write the filename also along with imagedata.